# Eclipse suggested fix for warning "finally block does not complete normally"

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, return, try-catch-finally

I know that returning in the finally block would lead to undesired results like uncaught exception getting lost. But what I am trying to understand here is Eclipse's suggested fix for the warning `"finally block does not complete normally"`.

Consider this code snippet:

```
    catch (SQLException se) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception occured in the database");
        System.out.println("Exception message: "+ se.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Database error code: "+ se.getErrorCode());
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up
        if(callStmt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                callStmt.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException se2) 
            {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        if(conn != null)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException se2) 
            {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        return newEmpSalary;
    }
}
```

For the above code `Eclipse Luna` gives the warning `"finally block does not complete normally"` , for which the suggested fix is:

[image]

Applying the above fix still does not make the warning go away.I know I just need to remove the return statement to get rid of it.

**But I am curious to know why Eclipse is suggesting the fix `"Change modifiers to final where possible"` in this case.**

Comment: No idea why it's saying that... the obvious solution is to move the return statement out from the finally block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse can't always figure a way out of the error so it suggests other things that might help or lead to a different error it does know how to fix.

Moving the `return newEmpSalary;` out of the finally block should remove the error.